# How do I make a C++ function implicitly convert a list of ints into a vector parameter?

Tags: c++, initialization, implicit-conversion, vmat

I am working on a library whose functions commonly take a vector type (`__v4si`, or a vector of 4 signed ints) as a parameter. (Note that so far this has nothing to do with the **C++ STL** `vector`template class; this is a more primitive construct used to let the compiler generate *vectorized* SIMD code.)

In my **C** code I customarily call a wrapper macro that takes a list of int arguments and initializes a `__v4si` like so:

```
#define MakeIndex(dims...) ((__v4si){ dims })
```

This of course works fine in **C++** too, but I would like to take advantage of **C++**'s more expressive type system to clean up calls to my libraries APIs. For example, where I now write something like:

```
long idx = IndexDotProduct(MakeIndex(1, 2, 3), MakeIndex(4, 5, 6, 7));
```

which macro-expands to:

```
long idx = IndexDotProduct(((__v4si){1, 2, 3}), ((__v4si){4, 5, 6, 7}));
```

I would like instead to be able to write something along the lines of:

```
long idx = IndexDotProduct({1, 2, 3}, {4, 5, 6, 7});
```

So, essentially (I think) I want to define a class that is just syntactic sugar around the primitive `__v4si` type, but that has an implicit cast operator for the list initializer.

How do I do that in **C++ 11**?

## Solution

Here is a formulation that works for both **C** and **C++** code (now using more verbose names as copied and pasted from my library header files):

```
typedef struct vMAT_Index {
    __v4si v;
#ifdef __cplusplus
    vMAT_Index(__v4si v) : v(v) { }
    vMAT_Index(int v0 = 0, int v1 = 0, int v2 = 0, int v3 = 0) : v((__v4si){ v0, v1, v2, v3 }) { }
#endif
} vMAT_Index;

#define vMAT_MakeIndex(dims...) ((vMAT_Index){ .v = { dims } })

static inline long
vMAT_Index_dot(vMAT_Index a,
               vMAT_Index b)
{
    __v4si c = a.v * b.v;
    return (long)c[0] + c[1] + c[2] + c[3];
}
```

In **C** code you still use the helper macro like this:

```
long idx = vMAT_Index_dot(vMAT_MakeIndex(1, 2, 3), vMAT_MakeIndex(4, 5, 6, 7));
```

But now in **C++** you can just write:

```
long idx = vMAT_Index_dot({ 1, 2, 3 }, { 4, 5, 6, 7 });
```

Thanks to nosid for providing the essential answer!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use implicit constructors to automatically create a vector object from a brace-initializer list:

```
struct vector
{
    vector(__v4si v);
    vector(int i0, int i1, int i2, int i3);
};

long IndexDotProduct(vector lhs, vector rhs);

long idx = IndexDotProduct(((__v4si){ 1, 2, 3 }), { 4, 5, 6, 7 });
```

Comment: Aha, thanks! I've pasted the code for a complete solution using this answer into the question above.